# How create API using repository pattern in dotnet core

Tags: .net-core, repository-pattern

Here is my code and I want to create API, from the repository methods.

This is Entity table of my code:

```
public partial class Course
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("DepartmentID")]
    public virtual Department  Department { get; set; }

    public int GradeLevelsID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("GradeLevelsID")]
    public virtual GradeLevels GradeLevels { get; set; }

    // Navigation 
    public virtual ICollection<Units> Units { get; set; }
 }
```

I need some output according to the methods:

- Create course for the particular Gradelevel
- Get Course of the GradeLevel
- Get All Unit of the course
  I write code for the following condition in the IRepository

  ```
  Public interface ICourseRepository
  {
      Task<Course> GetAllCourseByGradeLevleId(int id)
      Task<Course> UpdateCoursetAsync(int Id);
      Task<Action> CreateCourseAsync(Course Course);
      Task<Course> DeleteCourseAsync(int Id);
  }
  ```

And the Repository Methods will be as following:

```
public class CountryRepository : ICourseRepository
{
    public Task<Action> CreateCourseAsync(Course Course)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task<Course> DeleteCourseAsync(int Id)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task<Course> GetAllCourseByGradeLevleId(int id)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task<Course> UpdateCoursetAsync(int Id)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

My Problem is that I am  unable to write return type method and unable to fetch data from the relational table, as well as unable to write POST and PUT api for this conditions.

Here is my controller class:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class CourseController : ControllerBase
    {

        private readonly ICourseRepository _courseRespository;
        public CourseController(ICourseRepository courseRespository)
        {
            _courseRespository = courseRespository;
        }


        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IEnumerable<Course>> Get()
        {
            return await _courseRespository.GetAllCourseAsync();
        }


        public async Task<ActionResult<Course>> GetId(int id)
        {
            var result = await _courseRespository.GetAllCourseByIdAsync(id);
            if (result == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return result;
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Post(Course course)
        {
            // _courseRespository.CreateCourseAsync();
            // await _courseRespository.SaveChangesAsync();
            return CreatedAtAction("GetId", new { id = course.ID }, course);
        }
```

How can write PUT and POST in this condition.

Answer (score -1):

Try having a code like below,

```
[Route("Course")]
public class CountryRepository : ICourseRepository
{
    [Route("~/users/Create")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(Course))]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<Action> CreateCourseAsync(Course Course)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, resultObj);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Route` attribute must be used over controller and its actions.